# Query to get the first and last row in a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I ran the following query to get the first and last row from a table.

```
SELECT Start, End, Start1, End1
FROM
(SELECT Start AS Start, End AS End 
  FROM [TB1]  WHERE Id = 251 ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 1),
(SELECT Start1 AS Start1, End1 AS End1 
  FROM [TB2]  WHERE Id = 251 ORDER BY DateTime LIMIT 1);
```

I get the output as follows:

```
 Start      End      Start1      End1
 25.32      -98.55    null       null
 null       null      29.81      -98.32
```

I am trying to get the output in the below format:

```
 Start      End      Start1      End1
 25.32      -98.55   29.81       -98.32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like your question is "partial" and next will be how to do the same for all Id! See below

```
SELECT Id, Start, End, Start1, End1
FROM
(SELECT Id, Start, End 
 FROM (
   SELECT
     Id, Start AS Start, End AS END, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY DateTime DESC) AS win
   FROM [TB1])
 WHERE win = 1
) AS t1
JOIN
(SELECT Id, Start1, End1 
 FROM (
   SELECT
     Id, Start1 AS Start1, End1 AS End1,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY DateTime) AS win
   FROM [TB2])
 WHERE win = 1
) AS t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `max` so the result will be on one row.

```
SELECT max(Start) start, max(End) end, max(Start1) start1, max(End1) end1
FROM
(SELECT Start AS Start, End AS End 
  FROM [TB1]  WHERE Id = 251 ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 1),
(SELECT Start1 AS Start1, End1 AS End1 
  FROM [TB2]  WHERE Id = 251 ORDER BY DateTime LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first and last rows over a single table (rather than two), you can compute it using `ARRAY_AGG` with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options" in the UI).

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 251 AS Id, 10.0 AS Start, -15 AS `End`, DATE('2016-11-09') AS DateTime UNION ALL
  SELECT 251, 25.32 AS Start, -98.55, DATE('2016-11-10') UNION ALL
  SELECT 251, 29.81, -98.32, DATE('2016-01-01')
)
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Start, `End`)
            ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS first_row,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Start AS Start1, `End` AS End1)
            ORDER BY DateTime ASC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS last_row
FROM T
WHERE Id = 251;
```

In general, this will probably be a bit faster than using an analytic function, too, but I haven't done any specific comparisons.